Stimulus and Turbo not loading on Rails 7 application with Importmaps
I'm currently moving out from webpacker to use importmaps and sprockets on Rails 7 but I can't get the config right and get these errors in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "application". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".


Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@hotwired/stimulus". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Here are the different files. What do I get wrong?
config/importmap.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/scripts', under: 'scripts'
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/javascripts', under: 'javascripts'
pin_all_from 'vendor/javascript'

layouts/application.html.erb (extract). Turbo only works if I add turbo_include_tags, btw.
  <head>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
    <%= turbo_include_tags %>
    ...
  </head>

app/assets/config/manifest.js
//= link application.js

//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js

//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../builds

app/javascript/application.js
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "@hotwired/stimulus"
import "./channels"
import "controllers"

app/javascript/controllers/application.js
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

const application = Application.start()

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application

export { application }

app/javascript/controllers/hello_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.element.textContent = "Hello World!"
  }
}

I can see both Stimulus and Application in my importmap JSON.
    "application": "/assets/application-61a1fb89ed14a586a4ca6d042ba68b42f7e3f217eb6be4d304bf67e76401f633.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo.min-670aa8fec0caf84941464bb76faf6410aaabb2118b29ac6a4295df481093f051.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min-9ee583d7d64bfaf202b0cf48971a673d9ed18952ae7927c50015649aebe535b6.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading-d80f0feea68692981b568bbfef0ed4370b56927ae5c663421e8461a466f0618f.js",

Any clue what the issue could be? Thanks.

remove <%= turbo_include_tags %>

When I do, Turbo doesn't load anymore (window.Turbo is undefined)

you're importing Turbo with import "@hotwired/turbo-rails" already. make sure you're on the latest version of turbo-rails. import "./channels" don't use relative imports, you have to import from the importmap. import "@hotwired/stimulus" also not needed, this is imported in controllers/application.js already.

I updated the files/gems accordingly but I still get the same error. window.Turboand window.Stimulusare still undefined.

i see //= link application.js, do you have another application.js somewhere, like app/assets/javascripts/application.js? it might be loading instead of  app/javascript/application.js.

Yes, there are both app/javascript/application.js + app/javascript/controllers/application.js— I tried renaming the first one to app.js but I still got the same error.

did you verify that app/javascript/application.js is loading? because that's about all of my ideas.

Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78889874/importmap-rails-and-stimulus-when-working-with-rails-engines
